# Is there a way to reset a Mayavi scene after interaction?

Tags: python, mayavi

I am using Mayavi to show 3 planes (X,Y,Z) of a volume, and can use the mouse cursor to move each of the volume 'slices'. However, after interacting, the view can get really messy, and I can't find a button or shortcut to reset the scene to the orginal/default view it has on startup.

This is how the menu bar looks, but I don't understand why there isn't a reset button, since it seems like something that would be extremely useful.

[image: menu bar]

2D viewing using Pyplot even has a reset to orginal view button:

[image]

After looking at the mouse and keyboard interaction sections of [Mayavi docs](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/application.html#interaction-with-the-scene), the closest thing I can find is the 'r' shortcut, which you can use to "Reset the camera focal point and position. This is very handy.". But this is not what I am looking for though. Here's an example of how my plot can look after interacting:

[image]

Trying to manually undo my interactions or restarting the entire programme each time are not feasible options.